# Problem showing global spinner using redux and react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, spinner

i have button in my index.jsx page which dispatch an activate action

```
<StickyButton type="button" onClick={() => dispatch(activate(values))}>
  <span>{t("share.button.continue")}</span>
</StickyButton>;
```

and this action, dispatch another action call isRequesting() which i use it in my spinner to show spinner, then call a method in authService to activate user :

```
export const activate = (model) => async (dispatch) => {
  await dispatch(isRequesting());
  authService
    .activate(model)
    .then(async (result) => {
      authService.setSignedUp();
      await dispatch(fetchProfile());
      await dispatch(isRequested());
      history.push(`${routes.sign_up.base}${routes.sign_up.activated}`);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      dispatch(errorOccurred());
    });
};
```

and the authService activate function is :

```
function activate(model) {

  let request = {
    lang: encryptService.aesStaticEncrypt(localeService.getActiveLanguage()),
    ver: encryptService.aesStaticEncrypt(config.app_version),
    phoneNumber: encryptService.aesStaticEncrypt(utilService.formatMobileWithPrefix(userService.getMobile())),
    invoice: encryptService.aesStaticEncrypt(utilService.getRandomDigit()),
    value: {
      activationCode: encryptService.aesStaticEncrypt(utilService.formatActivationCode(model.activation_code)),
    },
  };
  return api
    .post(`${config.apiUrl}/GATEWAY/ACTIVATIONGATEWAY/V1/Activate`, request)
    .then(async (result) => {
      return Promise.resolve(result);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      utilService.handleError(error);
      return Promise.reject(error);
    });
}
```

and spinner component :

```
export const FullPageSpinner = () => {
  const { isRequesting } = useSelector((state) => state.request);
  console.log("FullPageSpinner");
  console.log(isRequesting);
  return (
    <div
      css={{
        position: "fixed",
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        fontSize: "3rem",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        backgroundColor: "#00000038",
        opacity: isRequesting ? 1 : 0,
        zIndex: isRequesting ? "9999999" : "-1",
      }}
    >
      <div css={{ alignSelf: "center", color: "#3e3e3e" }}>
        <Spinner />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

request reducer code :

```
import * as types from "../actionTypes/request";

const initialState = {
  isRequesting: false,
  isRequested: false,
};

export default function requestReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.type === types.IsRequesting) {
    return {
      ...state,
      isRequesting: true,
      isRequested: false
    };
  }
  if (action.type === types.IsRequested) {
    return {
      ...state,
      isRequesting: false,
      isRequested: true
    };
  }
  if (action.type === types.ErrorOccurred) {
    return {
      ...state,
      isRequesting: false,
      isRequested: true
    };
  }
  return state;
}
```

root reducer :

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import profileReducer from "./profile";
import requestReducer from "./request";
import appReducer from "./app";


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  profile: profileReducer,
  request: requestReducer,
  app: appReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

and create store :

```
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    (window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__()) || compose
  )
);
```

request actions :

```
import * as request_types from "../actionTypes/request";

export const isRequesting = () => {
  console.log("isRequesting");
  return {
    type: request_types.IsRequesting,
  };
};

export const isRequested = (messages) => {
  console.log("isRequested");
  return {
    type: request_types.IsRequested,
    payload: messages,
  };
};
```

request reducer :

```
const initialState = {
  isRequesting: false,
  isRequested: false,
};

export default function requestReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.type === types.IsRequesting) {
    return {
      ...state,
      isRequesting: true,
      isRequested: false
    };
  }
  if (action.type === types.IsRequested) {
    toastService.notify(action.payload);
    return {
      ...state,
      isRequesting: false,
      isRequested: true
    };
  }
  if (action.type === types.ErrorOccurred) {
    return {
      ...state,
      isRequesting: false,
      isRequested: true
    };
  }
  return state;
}
```

and AppComponent where i put the FullPageSpinner to render based on isRequesting

```
const App = () => {
  const { ltr } = useSelector((state) => state.language);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Routing />
      <ToastContainer
        position="bottom-center"
        autoClose={config.toast_auto_close}
        transition={Flip}
        {...(!ltr && { rtl: true })}
      />
      <FullPageSpinner />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default App;
```

the problem is when i dispatch isRequesting(), the state is changing but the spinner does not show up and it wait until the response of the authService.activate function which it could take some time to return.
i want the spinner to show immediately after i dispatch isRequesting() and not wait for the response of

Comment: Why are you awaiting the dispatches? Can you include your action creators and reducer code?

Comment: @DrewReese i updated the question.
by the way i remove the awaiting of dispatches but the problem not solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove unnecessary async/await from activate action creator:

```js
export const activate = (model) => (dispatch) => { // async here is not necessary
  dispatch(isRequesting()); // await here is not necessary
  authService
    .activate(model)
    .then(async (result) => {
      authService.setSignedUp();
      await dispatch(fetchProfile());
      dispatch(isRequested()); // await here is not necessary
      history.push(`${routes.sign_up.base}${routes.sign_up.activated}`);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      dispatch(errorOccurred());
    });
};
```

**EDIT:**

I looked at example you added in a sandbox and your implementation of  `authService.activate()` was not asynchronous there.

I provided fix here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xplsqp?file=services/auth.js

Your original `authService.activate()` is probably blocking and not asynchronous also.
So check your `api.post` if it is asynchronous. I also suggest some improvements of your code (check my comments):

```js
//autService.activate
//...
 return api
    .post(`${config.apiUrl}/GATEWAY/ACTIVATIONGATEWAY/V1/Activate`, request)
    .then(async (result) => { // remove async from here
      return Promise.resolve(result); // do not use Promise.resolve, just "return result;" is correct
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      utilService.handleError(error);
      return Promise.reject(error); // do not use Promise.reject here, if you want to recatch this error in next chain just "throw error;" instead
    });
// ...
```

Comment: actually all of async/await in this aciton are unnecessary and i removed all of them but the problem still remains.

Comment: Can you put here also implementation of your `isRequesting` and `isRequested` action creators?

Comment: yes, i updated the question and put those implementations.

Comment: That looks also ok. Could you add also a parent component where you are rendering `FullPageSpinner` and where you are using response of `activate`?

Comment: i updated the question and put the parent of FullPageSpinner which is AppComponent. by the way i don't use activate response,just redirect the user to another page based on response of activate which might take a while for server to respond

Comment: Thanks for that, but sorry I still cannot see any problem here. Can you create minimal example in some sandbox?

Comment: here is the sample code https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tvtnp7
clicking fetch data supposed to show the spinner but it's doesn't show up.

Comment: Thanks, I look at it and provided a fix of sandbox example and some suggestions in edit of my answer.

Comment: amazing, thanks for your time and answer. i refactored my code based on your recommendation.

Comment: I always wonder if having a global loading state has good performance considering that all connected components will receive an update when the loading state changes and probably there are many connected components (either with Redux or Context API).